# $\forall n,\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0\Leftrightarrow\forall n,\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x^n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is continuous function satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable at anywhere except $0$.

$(\Rightarrow)$

Assume that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x^n}=0
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then by L'Hospital's rule,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{nx^{n-1}}=0
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ because $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=0$ too.

$(\Leftarrow)$

I'm tried to show this, but I struck by showing existence of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x^n}$. If $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x^n}$ exists, then obviously $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x^n}=0$. Can we show this? Any ideas will be appreciated.